# Why isn't my .plist showing the saved data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, writetofile

I have a simple To-Do list where I add items to the list. I want to save these items to a .plist file when the app closes so that they display when the user re-opens the app.

I am currently trying 2 different methods. Both are giving me the `List successfully saved!` log entries but neither are displaying the file on re-launch.

Method 1:
In my `mainAppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *filePath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toDoItems.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *plistdict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [plistdict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


    if(![self.toDoItems writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"List Successfully Saved!");
    };
}
```

In my `XYZToDoListController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toDoItems.plist"];
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
```

Method 2:
In my `mainAppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toDoItems.plist"];


    if(![self.toDoItems writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"List Successfully Saved!");
    };
}
```

In my `XYZToDoListViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toDoItems.plist"];
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
     {
        self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSLog(@"Loading saved list");
     } else {
        self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Empty List");
     }
}
```

I'm fairly new to using objective C and I've read a lot of questions and answers but I can't seem to get my .plist file to load. Could someone help me figure out what is going wrong in my code with a nice example that applies to my situation?

As I said, in the log output I see that the "Empty List" method is loading and it is telling me "List Successfully saved!". Any debugging output beyond this I'm not sure how to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the file in NSDocumentsDirectory (as is appropriate)  But when you load it, you're just loading it from the application current directory (probably the application folder itself).  You're also writing an empty file just before you read it, try using the following in your app delegate:

```
-(NSString*)toDoFilePath
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *filePath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"toDoItems.plist"];

    return filePath;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self toDoFilePath]])
    {
        self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self toDoFilePath]];
        NSLog(@"Loading saved list");
    } else {
        self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Empty List");
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if([self.toDoItems writeToFile:[self toDoFilePath] atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"List Successfully Saved!");
    };
}
```

Assuming (as it appears) that you already have a toDoItems property on your app delegate.

To use the data from your view controller, after including your AppDelegate.h file, you can use:

```
self.toDoItems = [(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] toDoItems];
```

Comment: Better yet, just have a single app delegate method that you invoke to return the path to the plist file and move all of the loading/saving into the app delegate.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean in the comment please? You mean loading the data through the mainAppDelegate?

I tried using both methods I posted to add the NSDocumentDirectory path as you wrote but I'm still not getting the file to load.

Comment: Looking at your code again, you're also reading the (nonexistent) file just before you write it.

Comment: With your edit, I am not seeing any "List Successfully Saved!" logs on my output.

Comment: Because when I copied your code, I copied your faulty success check, writeToFile returns true on success, not false.  I've fixed the example.  Also probably best not to do saving in applicationWillTerminate, but instead do it when data is updated, but I've left it in place as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Yes- I did change `applicationWillTerminate` to `applicationDidEnterBackground` to make sure that it gets called. Great, ok I see it, yet the list is still not appearing! I changed my `viewDidLoad` method to: `[super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, so I'm guessing it's just taking this method and loading the blank array. What do I change it to to reference the delegate?

Comment: @Deannakov Added the appropriate stuff, what you're doing would just create another empty items list, ignoring the items list the AppDelegate is managing.

Comment: sigh, ok. I literally just copied and pasted what you had and its supposedly saving anything, and even tried changing some things that appeared suspicious but to no avail. Thanks for your time.